# Installed yarn globally, but nothing works

Tags: npm, hadoop-yarn

I completely messed up my ability to do any coding on my computer a few months ago and I was so frustrated that I walked away for awhile and now I have no recollection of how I even got myself into this mess. I tried running npm install --global yarn. It says it installed. I tried running yarn --version and i got

```
AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

I've also tried using npm run start for my projects and I get the same error. No matter what I type I just get error after error of command not found.